# Is there a method that is opposite of dimensionality reduction?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new to the field of machine learning, but have done my share of signal processing. Please let me know if this question has been mislabeled.

I have two dimensional data which is defined by at least three variables, with a highly non-linear model way too complicated to simulate.

I have had varying level of success at extracting the two main components from the data using methods like PCA and ICA (from the python library Scikit-Learn), but it seems these method (or at least, these implementation of the methods) are limited to extracting as many components as there are dimensions in the data, for example, 2 components from a 2D point cloud.

When plotting the data, it is clear to the *trained* eye that there are three different linear trends, the three color lines show the directions.

[image: data plot]

When using PCA, the main component is aligned to one of the color lines, and the other is at 90°, as expected. When using ICA, the first component is aligned with the blue line, and the second is somewhere in between the red and green ones. I am looking for a tool which could reproduce all three components in my signal.

**EDIT, Additional info:** I am here working in a small subset of a bigger phase plane. In this small subset, each input variables produce a linear change on the plane, but the direction and amplitude of this change is non-linear and depends on where exactly on the bigger plane I am working. At some places, two of the variables can be degenerate: they produce change in the same direction. for example, say the model depends on X, Y, and Z. A change in the variable X will produce a variation along the blue line; Y causes a variation along the green line; Z, along the red one.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the concept you are looking for is _embedding_. Look up _kernel methods_, and _kernel PCA_ in particular.

Comment: I am not sure about this, so I am not posting it as an answer. In a neural network type of model, you can keep the hidden layer dimensionality > input layer dimensionality. Then you can use the hidden layer as input to another network/model. But doing so requires lots of data.

Comment: When you say 2 dimensional data, defined by at least three variables, in what sense do you use the term 'variable'? Would classes be a suitable substitution ? It's worth noting that PCA extracts maximally variant dimensions from data, this is not necessarily the most discriminative transform to apply. Have you looked at clustering ?

Comment: Do you know anything about the nonlinearity of the model?  Though it may be too complex to simulate, knowing that it is at most made up of degree 3 polynomials restricts the feature engineering significantly e.g. you could add all 3rd degree polys and then PCA it back down to 3D.

Comment: I have discussed with a statistician friend of mine who suggested using kernel PCA on the **derivative** of my data, since I'm looking for slopes. Would taking the derivative count as "feature engineering"?

Comment: 6 years later. I found this paper useful: https://www.nature.com/articles/s42256-021-00322-1

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is yes.

Essentially you will be performing some sort of feature engineering. This means constructing a series of functions of your data, often:

$\phi_j(x): \mathbb R^p \rightarrow \mathbb R \ ,\ \  j=1,...,K$

Which, strung together, define a transformed data vector $\boldsymbol \phi(x)$ of length $K$.

There are a number of ways, better and worse, of doing this. You may want to look up terms like:

1. Splines and generalised additive models.
2. The kernel trick (how to make a model where $K\rightarrow \infty$).
3. Feature engineering (of the manual variety, e.g. adding an $x^2$ column to your data).
4. Deep learning, representation learning

As you might guess from such a varied bag of techniques, this is a large area. It goes without saying really but care has to be taken to avoid overfitting.

This paper [Representation Learning: A Review and New Perspectives](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5538.pdf) deals with some of the issues around what makes a particular set of features 'good', from a deep learning perspective.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you are looking for features which extract out new features. A feature which best represents the dataset. If that is the case then we call such method "feature extraction".